# How can I implement Staggered Grid View with Lazy Loading feature on Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, lazy-loading, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview

I am trying to create a wallpaper app with Staggered Grid View on Flutter, and for the purpose, I am trying to make use of Staggered Grid View Package on Flutter (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view). But the thing is, my list of wallpapers is getting big and it takes a lot of time to load all of the images at the same time.

After some searching, I came across Flutter-Pagewise Package, but don't know how can I implement with Staggered Grid View.

Comment: use `StaggeredGridView.builder` /  `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder` constructors

Comment: Well! They are just for construction the grid view, aren't they? Or are they able to handle the lazy loading sort of stuff, too?

Comment: https://dev.to/fallenstedt/building-widgets-on-demand-with-flutter-48dd

Comment: Hi @ltzkhan have you found solutions?? I have a same issue.

Comment: Sorry Zeck, wasn't able to solve the issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is to create a ScrollController()

Initialize the scroll controller to receive a notification on the end of the length of the item, make sure you add this controller to staggered grid view.

```
 _scrollController.addListener(() {
  if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
    _getmoreData();
  }
});
```

You can initialize the staggered grid view like this

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                          controller: _scrollController,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          itemcount: length + 1)
```

Inside the builder check for the index is equal to the length and you can display a circular progress indicator or indicator of your choice.